# svn ls with wildcards or explicit depth

Tags: svn

Is there a way to list files in the repository using wildcards?
I tried `svn ls "*/*"` but got

```
svn: warning: W155010: The node '/e/dir/*/*' was not found.
svn: E200009: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist
```

Another option that would work for me is an explicit depth, instead of `immediates` or `infinity` I would like to specify 2.

Answer (score 1):

--depth files only shows the files in the given directory but no subfolders. You could use grep if you only want to show files matching a given pattern.

```
svn ls some/folder --depth files | grep .jpg
```